# Using Beanstalkd in eJabberd module

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm using eJabberd as my XMPP server. I'm developing a module that will filter messages with `type=queue`, then will add them to work queue Beanstalkd.

**Problem:** Every time i get message with type="queue", i get connected to the beanstalkd.I believe this is incorrect.

**Approach:** I tried to put 
`{ok, Q} = beanstalk:connect(),` in `start(_Host, _Opt)`, but since `put(Pid, Data) -> put(Pid, Data,[])` requires Pid, **i have no idea how to pass Pid, from start to on_filter**.

```
    %% name of module must match file name
    -module(mod_beanstalkd).

    %% Every ejabberd module implements the gen_mod behavior
    %% The gen_mod behavior requires two functions: start/2 and stop/1
    -behaviour(gen_mod).

    %% public methods for this module
    -export([start/2, stop/1, on_filter_packet/1]).

    %% included for writing to ejabberd log file
    -include("ejabberd.hrl").
    -include("jlib.hrl").

    start(_Host, _Opt) -> 
        ?INFO_MSG("starting mod_beanstalkd", []),
        ejabberd_hooks:add(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 120).

    stop(_Host) -> 
        ?INFO_MSG("stopping mod_beanstalkd", []),
        ejabberd_hooks:delete(filter_packet, global, ?MODULE, on_filter_packet, 120).

    on_filter_packet({From, To, XML} = Packet) ->
        ?INFO_MSG("on_beanstalkd ~p~n", [Packet]),
        Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"type">>, XML),
        case Type =:= <<"service">> andalso DataTag =:= false of
        true -> 
            ?INFO_MSG("on_beanstalkd service = True", []),
            {ok, Q} = beanstalk:connect(),
            JSON = xml:get_tag_cdata(xml:get_subtag(XML, <<"body">>)),
            {inserted, ID} = beanstalk:put(Q, JSON),
            Return = Packet,
        false ->
            Return = Packet,
            ?INFO_MSG("on_beanstalkd ELSE Return ~p~n", [Return])
        end,   
        Return.
```